# Showing some parts of a external website and modifing HTML/CSS

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, web

I would like to know what is the best approach, based on good programming practices to show an external webpage (say Facebook or Twitter) on my website while being able to modify the HTML and CSS before showing it.

I know that I could use an iFrame however based on some opinions the iFrame does not seem to be a good programming practice (width issues, ugly scrollbars, etc).

Is there a better approach?

**Update:** Question was put on "too broad", in order to limit the possible answers I would like to know if it possible to change the CSS (and only CSS) of an iFrame, the user Muhammad Umer commented that it would be possible but provided no more details. Someone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a phishing attempt. Anyways, not possible due to [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: ifram isn't a good solution because you can't modify what is in unless  it's from same domain as yours. As we facebook won't so it will not work. Scroll bars and width are minor issues, and fixable.

Comment: Dave Chen, I am more or less aware of that misuse, the question about "How legal it is was closed thats why I just asked only this"... I feel required to explain the purpose. It is actually an attempt to make website more accesible for several psychomotor disabilties. What about only changing the CSS? No HTML or functionality. Is it possible?

Comment: Yesterday I read someting about that Facebook has build a new api which allowes you to add posts on your website. It was dutch and I didnt find a link to doc's, but ágain, api's are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in PHP. First I want to suggest to look for API's. Facebook has some nice API's which allow you to show them on your website, with some options to customize is.

The more difficult (and lots of work to maintain) is using `file_get_contents()` and using some parsers and regex to get the parts you want. Allthough facebook (and some other sites) might prove difficult, they load some parts via JS, so file_get_contents cant get everything

Again, API's are the way to go.

Comment: 2nd solution is just too hard..getting is one thing and making it work with sending is totally different. How would cookies be handled. But as far as Css goes i think it'd work fine. Though at each click all modifications would go out. So need to add base url and modify other urls that user interact with...ugh again way too hard actually.

Comment: Thats why I recommand the API's. It's doable, but allot of work

Comment: yea not to mention if site changes its structure every few month--never ending work.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer could yo please provide more information on changing the CSS of an iFrame that you mention?

Comment: I dont think he means loading in an iframe. Just loading the contents of 1 site into the source of your own.

Comment: Using server when you get the facebook page. You can then add your style sheet in html like `<style src='http://...'></style>` then send it to client. 

http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/